# file de un input type file

Tags: javascript

estoy realizando un proyecto y no entiendo esta parte de mi codigo

```
var data = new FormData();

$.each($('input[type=file]')[0].files, (i, file) =>{
    data.append('file', file);
})
```

Entiendo que obtiene del `input[0]` los archivos, pero después de la coma no entiendo la función que tiene **`(i, file)`**, para que sirve la variable `i` en este caso?

Comment: La variable `i` es el index del `eachs`, pero en si cual es tu problema solo saber para que esta la `i `?

Comment: Representa al indice del valor de la lista que se está iterando. Que aunque no lo uses en tu caso, va como primer parámetro del callback según la función [each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) de JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno aqui la respuesta `.each( function )` es un método que ejecuta una función la cual tiene dos parámetros `Function( Integer index, Element element )`, cuando nosotros la declaramos podemos llamar a estos parámetros como queramos, solo tenemos que tener en cuenta que el primero es el `índice (index)` en este caso la `i` que nos indica el número de elemento que está recorriendo y el segundo parámetro es el objeto de la lista el cual estamos iterando.

Comment: Es la respuesta, esta  preguntando para que sirve la `i` en la funcón

Answer (score 3):

es la acortación y el uso de arrow functions

```
$.each($('input[type=file]')[0].files, (i, file) =>{
    data.append('file', file);
})
```

el cual es el siguiente:

```
$.each($('input[type=file]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('file', file);
})
```

aca otro ejemplo de una arrow function

```
const sum = (x , y) => x + y;
```

y su equivalente es:

```
var sum = function(x,y){
   return x+y;
}
```

ahora bien por el jquery $.each lo que hace es iterar sobre un array donde en tu caso tenemos (i, file) donde i es el index y file es todo el objeto actual.

[aca otra explicación más extensa](https://www.anerbarrena.com/jquery-each-5297/)

Comment: el resto del contenido no es de mi autoria por eso no agrego todo

Answer (score 2):

El método `$.each()` lo que hace es recorrer una matriz de objetos ejecutando una función para cada iteración que realiza es decir para cada elemento del objeto. Tal y como se describe en su [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/each/) la función que ejecuta este método recibe dos parámetros, el primer parámetro de tipo `integer` que es el índice, y el segundo parámetro que es el elemento actual que está recorriendo.

```js
$(function(){
  $.each($('p'), function(index, elemento){
    console.log('El índice actual es: ' + index);
    console.log('El elemento actual es:');
    console.log(elemento);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Casa</p>
<p>Carro</p>
<p>Moto</p>
<p>Mascota</p>
<p>Familia</p>
```

El primer parámetro, osea el índice, siempre es obligatorio mientras que el segundo parámetro es opcional, debido a que por cada iteración también puedes acceder al elemento actual por medio de `this`

```js
$(function(){
  $.each($('p'), function(index){
    console.log('El índice actual es: ' + index);
    console.log('El elemento actual es:');
    console.log(this);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Casa</p>
<p>Carro</p>
<p>Moto</p>
<p>Mascota</p>
<p>Familia</p>
```

Ahora en tu código simplemente están usando el método corto de ES6:

```js
$(() => {
  $.each($('p'), (index, elemento) => {
    console.log('El índice actual es: ' + index);
    console.log('El elemento actual es:');
    console.log(elemento);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Casa</p>
<p>Carro</p>
<p>Moto</p>
<p>Mascota</p>
<p>Familia</p>
```